# Magento - Add field to actions in Catalog Price Rules

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add a custom field to the actions tab in the Catalog Price Rules section.

This is what I did:

1. I added these lines to the file app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Promo\Catalog\Edit\Tab\Actions.php

   ```
   $fieldset->addField('custom_field', 'select', array(
       'label'     => 'Custom Field',
       'title'     => 'Custom Field',
       'name'      => 'custom_field',
       'options'    => array(
           '1' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Yes'),
           '0' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('No'),
       ),
   ));
   ```
2. I changed the version to 1.6.0.4 in this file: app\code\core\Mage\CatalogRule\etc\config.xml

   ```
   <Mage_CatalogRule>
       <version>1.6.0.4</version>
   </Mage_CatalogRule>
   ```
3. I created new file with the name app\code\core\Mage\CatalogRule\sql\catalogrule_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.3-1.6.0.4.php

> ```
> $installer->startSetup();
> $ruleProductTable = $installer->getTable('catalogrule/rule');
> $columnOptions = array(
>     'TYPE' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
>     'UNSIGNED'  => true,
>     'NULLABLE'  => false,
>     'DEFAULT'   => 0,
>     'COMMENT'   => 'Custom Field',
> );
> $installer->getConnection()->addColumn($ruleProductTable, 'custom_field', $columnOptions);
> $installer->endSetup();
> ```

Then, I logged in to the admin panel and tried to edit one of the catalog price rules.

I saw my new field in the actions tab - great!

But when I click "Save", the changes that I made in that field, was not saved.

I logged in to the phpmyadmin and went to catalogrule table.
In this table I can see the new field custom_field, with the value 0 (default) - so It really didn't save the changed.

My question is what I did wrong?
Why the changed in the custom_field didn't saved in the DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it isn't working for you my guess is your installer isn't being called. I managed the modification through a module and local edits to future proof the change.

**Directory structure:**

```
/app/code/local/custom/promo
/app/code/local/custom/promo/etc/
/app/code/local/custom/promo/sql
/app/code/local/custom/promo/sql/promo_setup
/app/code/core/local/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab
```

add file /app/code/local/custom/promo/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Promo>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Custom_Promo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <promo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Promo</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </promo_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

add file /app/code/local/custom/promo/sql/promo_setup/install-1-0.php

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$ruleProductTable = $installer->getTable('catalogrule/rule');
$columnOptions = array(
    'TYPE' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
    'NULLABLE'  => false,
    'COMMENT'   => 'Custom Promo',
);
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($ruleProductTable, 'custom_promo', $columnOptions);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Clear caches and verify the column is added by looking at the catalog_rule table

```
SELECT * FROM catalogrule;
```

Finally take a copy of  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Main.php and create the same file  /app/code/core/local/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Main.php

Edit the file and add the field before $form->setValues($model->getData());

```
//Custom Promo
        $fieldset->addField('custom_promo', 'select', array(
            'label'     => 'Custom Promo',
            'title'     => 'Custom Promo',
            'name'      => 'custom_promo',
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('No'),
            ),
        ));
```